# Replacing a server seamlessly

Tags: migration, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint server at easyname.domain.com

I want to upgrade that server's OS and hardware by building a new system with better components.

The problem is, when you install SharePoint, a great deal of the system is tied to it's identity. So if I installed a mirror Farm at easynametemp.domain.com, and then did a backup restore from the original farm, I cannot just rename the machine and have everything work.

I assume there's a standard way to do this so that your farm isn't offline for an hour or two while you construct the machine.

Comment: What version of Sharepoint? The [top hit in a simple Google search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262370(v=office.12).aspx) seems to be an exact fit for your question.

Comment: What was the search? Why the downvote?

Comment: @Bryan This article has nothing to do with my question. It's all about content migration, and does not reference server namespacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommendation from a friend here:

Build the new machine with a new name, and then run Rename-SPServer from powershell to effectively rename the machine.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607556.aspx